# Is this Wonka character's name a pun?

Tags: character, wonka

In the 2023 movie, *Wonka*, the title character befriends others who befell similar misfortune to him...

> others who, like Willy, didn't read the fine print in Scrubitt's contract, and ended up in indentured servitude.

I recognize most of these characters' names as puns on their (former) jobs.

E.g. "Abacus Crunch" can be considered a pun on "crunching numbers", i.e. math-related work, along the lines of his previous job as an accountant. Also, his first name, "Abacus" could be a reference to [the ancient hand-operated counting tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abacus), adding another level of wordplay on the notion of his being a "number cruncher."

"Piper Benz" can be considered a pun on "bending pipes," ("Benz" is phonetically similar to "Bends") with dealing with pipes being a major part of her former job as a plumber.

The "Chucklesworth" in "Larry Chucklesworth" can be considered a pun on "chuckling", laughing, etc., in line with his former job as a standup comic.

I'm at a loss, though, whether "Lottie Bell" is a pun on anything related to her former job as a phone operator. The closest I could think of is the phrase "Ma Bell," a phrase connected to the Bell Telephone companies from earlier centuries... But I thought that might be a stretch, and that that might also be missing "Lottie" being part of the pun.

Does anyone know: is "Lottie Bell" a pun on any specific phrase related to telephone work?

Comment: The (fan-written) [Warner Bros Wonka wiki](https://warnerbros.fandom.com/wiki/Lottie_Bell?mobile-app=true&theme=false) suggests it's an allusion to to Alexander Graham Bell but I can't see anything that supports this assertion

Comment: There's also the fact that old-style telephones literally had bells on them to ring when a call came in.

Comment: @Valorum - so one way or another, it appears that the "pun" is exclusively from Lottie's last name, "Bell" and its associations to telephone history, and not from "Lottie" or "Lottie Bell" in its entirety(?)

Comment: Lottie is almost certainly a dimunuitive form of Charlotte. I can't see that Charlotte Bell would be any more of an obvious pun than Lottie Bell.

Comment: "The Bell System was a system of telecommunication companies, led by the Bell Telephone Company and later by the American Telephone and Telegraph Company (AT&T), that dominated the telephone services industry in North America for over 100 years from its creation in 1877 until its antitrust breakup in **1983**".  Yes, 1983 is in a previous century, but that's not exactly ancient history.  And even if legally Ma Bell ceased to exist in 1983, it didn't disappear from the public conciseness.  For example, [this line](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKZTzHk_UyY&t=7s) from the 1990 film Home Alone.

Answer (score 3):

[Alexander Graham **Bell**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Graham_Bell) invented the telephone.

> Alexander Graham Bell was a Scottish-born Canadian-American inventor, scientist and engineer who is credited with patenting the first practical telephone. He also co-founded the American Telephone and Telegraph Company (AT&T) in 1885.

His name is so synonymous with the telephone that e.g. in Dutch and German, when you telephone someone, you "bell" them (this is a rough translation, my point is that Bell's name is used as the verb for telephoning someone).

As to your question on where "Lottie" fits into the pun, you already established that Larry Chuckleworth's pun is related to his last name, not his first; so I see no reason why you'd expect Lottie's first name to relate to the pun.

Comment: I've downvoted for lack of evidence that this is what the pun is supposed to be, and I already pointed out this possibility in a comment above.

Comment: Also, are you sure that's where that expression comes from? I'm fairly sure that [phones having bells on](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=nErtuhFMtNc) is why people say "Ring me" or "Bell me" in British English.

Answer (score -2):

Although there is no direct evidence from the director or writers, I think it can be safely assumed that, as others have stated, Bell is most likely a reference both to Alexander Graham Bell (1), the inventor of the telephone, as well as back to when telephones literally had bells on them (see image below).

As for her first name Lottie, there is an argument for the possibility that there is no pun involved as others have mentioned.

However, a simple search on the Internet reveals that both the name Lottie itself and its presumed full name, Charlotte, as a feminine equivalent of the name Charles (Charlot, for short), can trace their origins to the Old English word for free man, "ceorl" or the Middle Low Germanic word for free man, "Kerle" (2, 3)

Along the way, they also gained the meanings of "petite" and "womanly" (3, 4).

Thus, as a woman who feels trapped and helpless in her job as a phone operator (5), it would then appear to somewhat also be plausible for Lottie Bell's name to mean and reference a "womanly" persona of "Alexander Graham Bell" who longs to be "free" from feeling trapped at her ho-hum job and in her humdrum existence.

> (1) Alexander Graham Bell (/ˈɡreɪ.əm/, born Alexander Bell; March 3, 1847 – August 2, 1922) was a Scottish-born Canadian-American inventor, scientist and engineer who is credited with patenting the first practical telephone. 
>  "[Alexander Graham Bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Graham_Bell)," *Wikipedia*

> (2) Charlotte and its masculine equivalent, Charles, are derived from the Old English word “ceorl,” meaning “free man.” The word ceorl was used to distinguish a free person from a bondsman or slave (thew) on one hand, and a noble person (eorl) on the other. 
> Origin: Charles is the French spelling of the Germanic name Carl (or Karl). Charlot originated as a nickname for Charles, with Charlotte being the feminine form. 
> "[Charlotte Name Meaning](https://www.verywellfamily.com/charlotte-name-meaning-origin-popularity-5182474)," *verywellfamily*

> (3) Lottie is a popular feminine given name that has its roots in several languages, including French, English, and German. It is a diminutive form of the name Charlotte, which means “free man,” and is also related to Lieselotte, Lotte, Lisa, Elisa, and Elisabeth. 
>  The name Lottie has a possible French origin, where it is associated with being “little” and “womanly.” It is believed to derive from the Middle Low Germanic word “Kerle,” which means “free man.” Hence, Lottie can be interpreted as “Freeman,” with “man” referring to an individual. 
>  "[Lottie Name Meaning](https://www.nameoftheyear.com/lottie-name-meaning/)," *Name of the Year*

> (4) Charlotte is an antique name with a royal history – and it's having quite a comeback. The name is of French origin, means "free man" or "petite," and is the feminine form of Charles. 
>  "[Charlotte](https://www.babycenter.com/baby-names/details/charlotte-954)," *babycenter*

> (5) Lottie Bell is one of the people who work under Bleacher and Scrubitt, two evil businessmen who exploit their workers and steal inventions from other inventors. She is assigned to operate the telephone switchboard and connect calls for them. She is unhappy with her job, but feels trapped and helpless. 
>  [Role in the Film](https://warnerbros.fandom.com/wiki/Lottie_Bell#Role_in_the_film), "Lottie Bell," *Warner Bros. Entertainment Wiki*

[image: ~~1880 Charles Williams Jr. 3 Box Telephone Set made for The American Bell Telephone Company with a Blake Transmitter and 101 Bell Telephone Receiver.]

Image Credit and Description 
 [~~ 1880 Charles Williams Jr. 3 Box Telephone Set made for The American Bell Telephone Company with a Blake Transmitter and 101 Bell Telephone Receiver](http://www.tomsantiquetelephones.com/american-bell.html), "American Bell Telephones," *Tom's Antique Telephones*

Comment: Hi Ben, what is the function of the image here?

Comment: This is a rewrite of the existing answer.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger I would disagree since I also add references for possible meanings for the first name whereas the existing answer says there is no related pun/meaning.

Comment: @jaochim It is to show OP a picture of an old telephone that still had bells in case OP has never seen one before. I mentioned it in the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger In addition, while we cited the same Wikipedia article when referencing Alexander Graham Bell, the existing answer also mentioned the phrase "Belling someone" in German and Dutch which I did not mention in my answer since that is not something I had known on my own. My point is, while I of course had to mention Bell (for which I also gave credit to the existing answer for bringing up despite it being common general knowledge), I was not "rewriting" or "copying" the existing answer as I only spoke about the parts that I knew and understood and had researched myself.

Comment: The existing answer is bad (in my opinion) and this is just a reworded version. And equally bad.

Comment: Just my 2 cents, but "Charlotte" never meant "free man" or "petite" in French. Lottie is *never ever* used by french people. It's a feminization of the name "Charles" (true). Sometimes, a girl named Charlotte will be called "Chacha" but there's no real diminutive for that name. I've spent more than 5 décades in France, am fluent in that language and I'm puzzled by that source...

Comment: @OldPadawan The reference I had used had mentioned how the name had come from the Middle Low Germanic word for free man, "Kerle," but I had not mentioned this specifically in my answer, so I have edited my answer to include this. I also added another resource that mentions the meaning of Charles/Charlotte from the Old English word "ceorl," which also means "free man," so hopefully, this helps to further clarify things.